# Closing a view controller through its delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following protocols:

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func closeViewController()
}

protocol MyProtocol: class {
    weak var delegate: SomeClass? {get set}
}
```

And the following class:

```
class SomeClass: MyDelegate {
    var myViewController: UIViewController

    init(myViewController: UIViewController){
        self.myViewController = myViewController
        self.myViewController.delegate = self
    }    

    func closeViewController() {
        myViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The idea here is that SomeClass takes a view controller and sets itself as the view controller's delegate.

The View controller is defined like so:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    weak var delegate: SomeClass?

    ...

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.closeViewController()
    }

    ...
}
```

where the close function is mapped to a close button in storyboard.

I initialize both SomeClass and my view controller inside another view controller.

```
var someViewController = // initialized here
var someClass = SomeClass(myViewController: someViewController)
self.present(someViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, when I press the close button, nothing happens at all. The view controller does not dismiss.

On the other hand, if I change the close() function in my ViewController to be:

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then it dismisses itself as expected, showing that the function is correctly mapped to the button.

How do I go about dismissing my view controller from another class?

Comment: Is the question how to dismiss a view controller from another class, as in all instances of that class, or is the question how to dismiss a view controller from another object of another class?

Comment: @slickdaddy The latter

Comment: And what is the relationship between the object and the view controller that needs to be dismissed? How are they connected?

Comment: The code in the question explains all this @slickdaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `delegate` property as weak and there isn't any strong reference of `SomeClass` object. Object should be `nil` by the time close button callback and `closeViewController()` is never called.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: you can remove the `weak`. there isn't any strong reference to the `SomeClass` object only view controller will have the strong reference.

Answer (score -1):

If I may suggest that you've made this much more complicated than it needs to be. I would ditch the `protocol` altogether and just implement a simple delegate pattern.

```
class SomeViewController {
    func close() {
        print("did close")
    }
}

class SomeObject {
    weak var delegate: SomeViewController?
    func close() {
        delegate?.close()
    }
}

let viewController = SomeViewController()
let object = SomeObject()
object.delegate = viewController

object.close() // prints "did close"
```